# Insert row in self-sizing collection view - Glitch

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I've been learning about self sizing `UICollectionViewCell`'s. It's all clear and easy by faced couple of problems.

Following this tutorial : [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@wasinwiwongsak/uicollectionview-with-autosizing-cell-using-autolayout-in-ios-9-10-84ab5cdf35a2) the guy has explained it very well. After I've downloaded the project in each cell we can see a problem with layout:

[image]

Second problem is that when we insert new item in a row using simple code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        randomTexts.append("sasojsfijfsiahfsifhiafs")
        collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)])
    }
```

We can observe messy animation insertion as well as a new inserted cell didin't go to row = 0 and section = 0, but to the last.

Any ideas why is that happening ? Any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I really understand your first problem. But for the second the problem could come from the fact that your new item "sasojsfijfsiahfsifhiafs" is append at the end of your list of data. So when the data are reloaded your new line appears as the last line.
You need to add your new item at the beginning of your list.

Use: randomTexts.insert("sasojsfijfsiahfsifhiafs", at: 0)

I hope it will help.

Comment: You are right about the second one. Still we stick with first one glitch.

Comment: Try to add minimum height for your rows ?! Does your code is on github so I can look at it ?

Comment: The link for git is in the tutorial

Comment: I don't see any problem when I test it on my iPhone 6S

Comment: Open the debug window as I have shown and also insert the row.

Comment: I don't think you should bother with that. I did a few test on Device and Simulator and it's working perfectly well. my searches suggest that this warnings are due to the fact that your sizes are dynamic, but xCode is looking for fixed constraints. If you continu looking for a solution to this problem and you find something, please let me know. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you ! I am going to try and let you know.

Comment: @noname, did you find anything for this issue bcoz I facing the same. Inserting new cell showing with some jump scroll.